# What is it called when you call someone on the phone over and over again?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang

What is it called when you call someone on the phone over and over again? I'm looking for a slang word or phrase.

Comment: Do you get a busy signal? Do you hang up when they answer? Do you hang up when the call goes to voicemail?

Comment: It is probably *harassment*, but that is not specific to phone calls.

Comment: Could it be infatuation?

Comment: With texts, by extension of e-mail, it's spamming. Oddly, I've never heard of tele-spamming, but I don't know another word for that. On the receiving end, you call them "nuisance calls" or "nuisance callers" (or something more rude).

Comment: Pestering.  Or, in my son's case, losing a friend due to OCD.

Answer (score 12):

It's called [blowing up their phone](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+up+her+phone):

> To call someone repeatedly and/or send someone a lot of text messages. — Farlex Dictionary of Idioms via TFD

See also the expression in [The Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/blow-up).

Answer (score 0):

Buggin’. That’s a 90’s slang word for it if you wanted to go with just the one word.

Comment: As far as I'm aware (and I did live through the 90s, though I was a child), "bugging" is just another term for "bothering," not specifically calling someone over and over on the phone.

Comment: This would benefit from a source and an explanation.  I associate that with *trippin'* as far as 90s slang goes, like saying "you're crazy" to mean "not making sense."  I encourage you to take the [tour] of the site and see the [help] for how to answer.